# Combining collection results of multiple MATCH cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in which, there can exist three patters of paths between `(:srcType)` and `(:destType)`:

1. **Pattern 1**
   `(:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(center)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(:destType)`
   Notice that, here the direction of relationships reverses as path goes through `(center)`:`<-[]-(center)-[]->`
2. **Pattern 2**
   In this pattern `(srcParent)` it self is a center. Thus direction of relationships reverses across `(srcParent)`:
       `(:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(:destType)`
3. **Pattern 3**
   In this pattern `(destParent)` it self is a center. Thus direction of relationships reverses across `(destParent)`:
   `(:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(:destType)`

I am giving id of `(:srcType)` and trying to obtain all `(:destType)` nodes. Note that given one `(:srcType)` it can have one `(:destType)` node associated with it following first pattern, another following 2nd pattern and few more following third pattern. I am trying to retrieve single collection containing all these `(:destType)` nodes. So I have combined above queries as follows:

```
MATCH (src:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(center)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest1:destType)
WHERE id(src)=3
WITH dest1
MATCH (src:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest2:destType)
WHERE id(src)=3
WITH dest1, dest2
MATCH (src:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest3:destType)
WHERE id(src)=3
RETURN dest1, dest2, dest3
```

So here I am matching each pattern one by one in `MATCH` clauses and feeding `(:destType)`s output of one `MATCH` to next one using `WITH` clause. At the end I am returning all `destType`s.

**Q1.** But this is not executing. When I run one of the pattern (single `WITH`), it correctly returns whichever `(:destType)` that matches the path. But with above query it returns 0 rows. Why is it so?

**Q2.** Also instead of returning all `destType`s, I want to return single collection containing elements of all of them. Knowing that collections can be merged using `+`, is it possible to return something like below?

```
RETURN destType1+destType2+destType2
```

**Note**
I will need to add different filters for each pattern afterwards. So the future query may look something like this:

```
MATCH (src:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(center)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest1:destType)
WHERE id(src)=3 AND srcParent.prop1='a'
WITH dest1
MATCH (src:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest2:destType)
WHERE id(src)=3 AND destParent.prop2='b'
WITH dest1, dest2
MATCH (src:srcType)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest3:destType)
WHERE id(src)=3 AND srcParent.prop3='c'
RETURN dest1, dest2, dest3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that these patterns may or may not be present, and that you want a collection of all results at the end, a good approach would be to match on the src node first, then use OPTIONAL MATCHes, and collect the results along the way, adding new ones in.

If we modify your last query, it may look something like this:

```
MATCH (src:srcType)
WHERE id(src) = 3
OPTIONAL MATCH (src)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(center)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest1:destType)
WHERE srcParent.prop1='a'
WITH src, COLLECT(dest1) as dests
OPTIONAL MATCH (src)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)-[]->(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest2:destType)
WHERE destParent.prop2='b'
WITH src, dests + COLLECT(dest2) as dests
OPTIONAL MATCH (src)<-[]-()<-[]-(srcParent)<-[]-(destParent)-[]->()-[]->(dest3:destType)
WHERE srcParent.prop3='c'
RETURN dests + COLLECT(dest3) as dests
```

Comment: So single `MATCH` with comma separated patterns or multiple `MATCH` without `OPTIONAL` actually ANDs the match crieterias?

Comment: got `Unexpected error during late semantic checking: Variable '  dest@523' not defined`

Comment: I added `as destsX`,`as destsY` and `as destsZ`. No rows. Now debugging it.

Comment: Also made even first `MATCH` optional, plus added `WHERE id(src)=?` on every `MATCH` as if first `MATCH` fails none of the second and third will get valid `src`. With these changes, its working as expected.